# TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

while running tensorflow got error as
 **TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.**

my code is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
w = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
cost = tf.add(tf.add(w**2, tf.multiply(-10,w)), 25)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session = tf.session()
session.run(init)
session.run(w)
```

I am running version 1.2.0
got many question like that but not good answer.
could you explain what is hapening? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to multiply an integer (i.e. 10) and a float variable (w). TensorFlow needs the input types to match for the multiplication to happen. So make sure all your inputs to `tf.multiply` and `tf.add` are the same type.

Change your line,

```
cost = tf.add(tf.add(w**2, tf.multiply(-10,w)), 25)
```

to

```
cost = tf.add(tf.add(w**2, tf.multiply(-10.0,w)), 25.0)
```